# Grails 3 and Spring Security: return 401 when user is not logged in

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security

In my Grails 3.2.9 web-app I'm using Spring Security plugin to manage user session. This is the depencency:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1"
```

The natural (years-long) evolution of the app brought to have basically all actions in all controllers, mostly secured using `@Secured` annotations, to return a JSON, with something like

```
return map as JSON    // grails.converters.JSON
```

That means that all actions are basically acting like APIs.

But since they're secured, when user is not logged, a redirect is performed to `/login/auth` (login page), which is something you wouldn't expect. This is why I'm searching for a way to return `401 unauthorized` status instead of letting Spring Security perform a redirect.

So far I've looked into [pessimistic lockdown](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/#pessimistic-lockdown), and searches across the web also lead me to [Spring Security Core REST plugin](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/), but both ways don't seem to adapt to my case (to me at last, but maybe I'm missing something).

So any suggestion is welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register the following in `resources.groovy`

`authenticationEntryPoint(Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint, 'Bearer')`

Comment: This worked like magic! :D No way I would have been able to get to this solution. Actually after some research it's still a bit fuzzy to me to get the whole picture.. could you please provide one reference you think it's the best for this case? That would really help

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted. I don't have a reference. I looked how the source code worked and did what was appropriate

Answer (score 0):

I do not have experience in Grails but perhaps what you are looking for can be implemented by providing a different implementation of `org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint` in your Spring security configuration. By default for form authentication Spring uses `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` which performs redirect to the given login page. On the other hand `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint` just returns the desired status.

In our project entry point is set in the old fashioned way through XML configuration:

```
<http pattern="/**" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="yourAuthenticationEntryPoint">
```